# AIR App in a DVD

Tags: actionscript-3, air, dvd-burning

I've created an Air app that includes a quiz and some videos. One of the videos is an embedded .flv clip which plays fine. However, the FLVPlayBack video which is an external .mov file doesn't show/play when I burn the app to a DVD. Also, the FLVPlayBack Controls such as stop/play buttons are no show.

I made sure the external .mov file is in the correct path and present in the DVD. I also tried different exports like mpeg4,mp4 etc. Burning it using Nero and as a Data DVD UDF. Everything works fine if the app is running on my computer.

Can someone point me to the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: What do you mean by ".mov file is in the correct path" ? Are you talking about a local path in your machine or a path in your DVD ? Is it an absolute path or a relative one ?

Comment: In Flash, it shows under Properties Tab > Component Parameters > source: myVideo.mov   --  So, I take that, it is at root and I should have the myVideo.mov file at the root of the DVD along with the main swf and FLVPlayBack player skin file. The main swf, player skin and .mov are in the same folder in my machine. So, I carry that folder structure to the DVD when burning.

Comment: So your final user will run the main swf ? Or what exactly ?

Comment: I publish the application with AIR so the final user will run the.exe file Adobe Air created. So, user inserts the DVD watches the video and takes an as3 quiz. It all works fine when I run the exe in my machine but when I burn it to DVD, everything works but the video is no show.